# How to know the final partition size to be used with physical extent (PE)

Tags: lvm

How do I know the size of the final partition size to use it as a physical extent (PE). For example, I would like to use 50 PEs of 16MiB each one. I had created one partition of 16x50 with cfdisk = 800M.

```
# vgcreate vgtest /dev/sdb2 -s 16M
# vgdisplay vgtest | grep "PE Size"
  PE Size               16,00 MiB 
# lvcreate vgtest -L 800M -n lvtest
  Volume group "vgtest" has insufficient free space (47 extents): 50 required.
#
```

My question is: Which final size (i.e. cfdisk = **800M**) should be in MB with the initial data of 16MiB of PEs size in VG and 50 PEs?

Comment: Hi @costales what do you mean by PEs?

Comment: @Goro this one:
[root@localhost ~]# vgdisplay vgtest | grep "PE Size"
  PE Size               16,00 MiB
[root@localhost ~]#

Comment: I meant what PEs stands for?

Comment: Are you sure that the partition is indeed 800MiB (838.860.800 bytes) or is 800 MB (800.000.000) bytes? Because `800,000,000 / 16,777,216 = 47.68`, which is just the number of extents LVM claims to have available.

Comment: @Goro: Physical extent. The basic allocation unit of LVM.

Comment: @Sven I would say 800MB, but how could I calculate the need size of the LV? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PV (physical volume), in that case the partition you created, needs to have enough space for 50 extents of 16 MiB, so 800 MiB or ~839 MB in SI units.

It is important to use the same base unit when dealing with this stuff - using base 2 units (MiB) in one place and base10/SI units in another leads to difficulties.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Note that LVM has a bit of overhead itself for the volume headers, so in reality, you need a bit more then 800 MiB.

Comment: Thanks! Then for know the final size would be 1024x1024x800MiB / 1000x1000 = 839MB :)